# How to remove duplicate sequences from a large fasta file quickly in python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I have downloaded some fasta files from NCBI database and they contain >10,000 sequences.

The file is like this:

```
>lcl|AY289593.1_prot_AAQ74417.1_1 [protein=FabH-like protein] [protein_id=AAQ74417.1] [location=complement(<1..775)] [gbkey=CDS]
MRPINDIQVDGVPNDHTIVQSDYISFTEADEPATVMATRAATEALTTSELVSADVGVLIYAAIIGDAHHF
APVCHVQRVLRAPDALAFELSAASNGGTQGIAVAANLMTADAPVKAALVCTAYRHPIDIISRWSSGMVFG
DGAAAAVLSRDGGMVRLISGYHGSLPELEVLARNRSNERLGFVLPDVGLGKYLTAIARMYQAVIAQVLEE
AQTSIAEIDYFGLIGIGIPSLTATILEPNGIPVNKTSWGLLRQMGHVG
>lcl|AY289593.1_prot_AAQ74418.1_2 [protein=type I polyketide synthase loading module] [protein_id=AAQ74418.1] [location=4126..>6747] [gbkey=CDS]
MLGDAVAVVGMSCRVPGASDPDALWALLRDGISVVDEIPSARWNLDGLVAHRLTDEQRSALRHGAFLDDV
EGFDAAFFGINPSEAGSMDPQQRLMLELTWAALEDARIVPEHLSGSSSGVFTGAMSDDYTTAVTYRAAMT
AHTFAGTHRSLIANRVSYTLGLRGPSLVIDTGQSSSLVAVHVAMESLRREETSLAIAGGIHLNLSLAAAL
SAAHFGALSPDGRCYTFDARANGYVRGEGGGVVVLKRLNDALADGNHIYCVIRGSSVNNDGATQDLTAPG
VDGQRQALLQAYERAEIDPSEVQYVELHGTGTRLGDPTEAHSLHSVFGTSTVPRSPLLVGSIKTNIGHLE
GAAGILGLIKTALAVHHRQLPPSLNYTVPNPKIPLEQLGLRVQTTLSEWPDLDKPLTAGVSSFSMGGTNA
HLILQQPPTPDTTQTPNPTTGSDPAVGSDSAVGSDPAVGVLVWPLSARSAPGLSAQAARLYQHLSAHPDL
DPIDVAHSLATTRSHHPHRATITTSIEHHSENNHDTTDALAALHALANNGTHPLLSRGLLTPQGPGKTVF
VFPGQGSQYPGMGADLYRQFPVFAHALDEVAAALNPHLDVALLEVMFSQQDTAMAQLLDQTFYAQPALFA
LGTALHRLFTHAGIHPDYLLGHSIGELTAAYAAGVLSLQDAATLVTSRGRLMQSCTPGGTMLALQASEAE
VQPLLEGLDHAVSIAAINGATSIVLSGDHDSLEQIGEHFITQDRRTTRLQVSHAFHSPHMDPILEQFRQI
AAQLTFSAPTLPILSNLTGQIARHDQLASPDYWTQQLRNTVRFHDTVAALLGAGEQVFLELSPHPVLTQA
ITDTVEQAGGGGAAVPALRKDRPDAVAFAAALGQ

>lcl|AY289596.1_prot_AAQ74421.1_1 [protein=type I polyketide synthase extender module] [protein_id=AAQ74421.1] [location=<1..>4439] [gbkey=CDS]
DTACSSSLVAIHLACQSLRNNESQLALAGGVTVMSTPAVFTEFSRQRGLAPDGRCKAFAATADGTGFGEG
AAVLVLERLSEARRNNHPVLAIVAGSAINQDGASNGLTAPHGPSQQRVINQALANAGLTHDQVDAVEAHG
TGTTLGDPIEAGALHATYGHHHTPDQPLWLGSIKSNIGHTQAAAGAVGVVKMIQAITHATLPATLHVDQP
GPHIDWSSGTVRLLTEPIQWPNTNHPRTAAVSSFGISGTNAHLILQQPPTPNPTQTPEDCSPAQSPCATI
TDAGTGLSFVPWVISAKSAEALSAQASRLLTRLDDDPVVDAIDLGWSLIATRSMFEHRAVVVGADRHQLQ
RGLAELASGNLGADVVVGRARAAGETVMVFPGQGSQRLGMGAQLYEQFPVFAAAFDDVVDALDQYLRLPL
RQVMWGDDEGLLNSTEFAQPSLFAVEVALFALLRFWGVVPDYVIGHSVGELAAAQVAGVLSLQDAAKLVS
ARGRLMQALPAGGAMVAVAASQHEVEPLLVEGVDIAALNAPGSVVISGDQAAVRLIANRLADRGYRAHEL
```

I didn't list the full file here because it's huge and it contains duplicates(pay attention to the strings right after "*prot*"), so I wrote a script like this to remove duplicates:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import pandas as pd                                                               
import sys

inputFile = sys.argv[1]
inputName = inputFile.split('.')[0]

idList = []

seqiter = SeqIO.parse(inputFile, 'fasta')

sys.stdout = open(inputName + '_nodup.fasta', 'w')                               

for record in seqiter:
    if record.description not in idList:
        idList.append(record.description)
        SeqIO.write(record,sys.stdout, "fasta")

sys.stdout.close()
```

It does the job but very slow.

I think there should be a smarter way to do this, any expert can help? Thank you!

Comment: A super-easy change to start with; `idList = []` is instead `idSet = set()` and `idList.append(record.description)` --> `idSet.add(record.description)` and finally, `if record.description not in idSet:`

Comment: That will pull the lookup time down from `O(n)` to `O(1)` provided that `record.description` is always hashable

Comment: WOW, Thank you so much!Definitely try this!

Comment: And the idea of using a `set` rather than a `list` can probably be pushed further still, since it will naturally kick out duplicates on conversion, but I'm out of my depth on the library by that point to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh! I'm learning more about 'set' myself now.

Comment: @roganjosh I figured it out, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I _think_ you could push it to deleting the entire `for` loop to simply be `idList = list(set([item.description for item in sqiter]))` and then handle the writing to file separately in a new `for` loop But, I don't know the library, I can't test from my phone and NOTE: the ordering of items in that list may be changed if you're in an earlier version of python, and that may be important (no idea if it is)

Comment: `idSet` is empty? That's more than I can debug from my phone. I think I covered all the necessary changes in my first comment so maybe revert the code back and try a second time. Someone should hopefully pick up on my comments and convert to an answer or I'll revisit when I get home.

Comment: Or answer it yourself :) I'm not fussed about reputation, happy just to try guide people to their own solution on this kinda thing